# issue with search input shows scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using w3layouts theme called pinball here is the link for the [theme](http://preview.w3layouts.com/demos/pinball/web) and i'm trying to add search and yes i was able to add search to it but the issue i'm having with search is when you were to search for lets say music it does show the results for music but you will have to scroll down to see the results like there is big gap between results which is the main issue i want the results to be shown below the menu any help will be appreciated here is the link for http://jsfiddle.net/nxfe7r29/3/

Screenshot of the issue

http://prntscr.com/6618e4

**HTML for input**

```
<form>
    <input id="search" type="text" /><input type="submit" value="" />
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
var search = $("#search");
var listItems = $("li");

search.on("keyup", function() {
  var terms = search.val();
  if (terms == '') {
    listItems.show();
  } else {
    listItems.hide(); 
    $("li:contains('" + terms + "')").show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's doing this because of the inline styling that is applied. All of these "cards" are being set to `position: absolute` with inline styling. That means they are fixed to that exact spot on the page.

So when you start searching for "life" or "movies" it hides the other elements on the page (with `display: none` utilizing jQuery's `hide()`.). But you have to scroll down because those elements are absolutely positioned lower in the document and they won't move up.

As for the solution: It depends on your familiarity with JavaScript & editing theme files.

- Somewhere in the theme files there is some logic to absolute position these elements. A different method should be used. This could involve a theme redesign depending on how it is done.
- See if there is an option/setting that you're missing in the theme for search mode.
- Pick a different theme
- Hire someone to do one of these things for you :)

Comment: Updated my answer with some possible solutions. They aren't great options. I'm not familiar with this theme to know where the problem is being introduced. So I can't offer more specific help other than what I've outline above.

Comment: it has  too many bugs i was planning to move on to next theme i have spent over a month on recreating the theme with fixed bugs and search was last thing

Comment: That bites to have to move on after so much time. But probably wisest.

Comment: i removed all of the css http://jsfiddle.net/nxfe7r29/8/ but  the issue seems to be coming from javascript can you take a look at it if you don't mind thanks

Comment: and i did put the javascript separate from html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rewrite your javascript code.

The Wookmark Jquery Plugin is organizing the blocks. You have to write your code according to their rules:
https://github.com/GBKS/Wookmark-jQuery

Their Filter would solve your problem

Comment: Yes and he is using an older version of the plugin. 
1) Update to the latest version of the plugin. 
2) Then update your current javascript
3) Utilize the filter functionality. to do this you'll need to add filter data types to your li's - eg, <li data-filter-class='["music"]'>
4) Update your search function and instead of showing/hiding results do something like this: var wookmark = new Wookmark('#tiles');
wookmark.filter([terms]);

Comment: i gave up on this :) moving on to next theme thanks guys for helping :)

Comment: im going to be building the theme from scratch i loved the concept of the theme sad part is i spent over a month on fixing the bugs it had now its time for me to move on and start from scratch with basics :)